# Normalize aggregation results according to number of days per month

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this table:

| Month | nbr_of_days | aggregated_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 120 |
| 2 | 28 | 70 |
| 3 | 30 | 130 |
| 4 | 31 | 125 |

My goal here is to normalize the aggregated sum to an assumed value of 30 (nbr_of_days) per month.

So for the first row, for example, the normalized aggregated_sum would be: 30*120/25=144

How to do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- df%>% mutate(normalized_aggregated_sum=30*aggregated_sum/nbr_of_days)
```

Note: while asking the question, I realized how it can be answered